# Unhandled exception at 0x778715de in opencv_helloworld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, opencv

I keep getting the same error, this line of code seems to be the problem i also add those line you told me

CvSeq *hand = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, hstorage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(100, 100));

Any great ideas?

```
// OpenCV_Helloworld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Created for build/install tutorial, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and OpenCV 2.1.0

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

IplImage* img = 0;

static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;
CvMemStorage *cstorage;
CvMemStorage *hstorage;

void detectObjects( IplImage *img );
int key;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture;
    IplImage *frame;

    // Create a string that contains the cascade name
    const char* cascade_name ="C:/Users/Mario/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/opencv_helloworld/1256617233-2-haarcascade_hand.xml";
    cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

    if (cascade == 0)
    {
        printf("No se encontro el archivo xml\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    hstorage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
    cstorage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

    cvNamedWindow( "camerawin", 1 );

    while(key!='q') {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;

        detectObjects (frame );

        key = cvWaitKey( 10 );
}

    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &cstorage );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &hstorage );

    return 0;
}

void detectObjects( IplImage *img )
{
    //int px;
    //int py;
    int edge_thresh = 1;
    IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width,img->height), 8, 1);
    IplImage *edge = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width,img->height), 8, 1);

    cvCvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);                       

    gray->origin=1;                         

    cvThreshold(gray,gray,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);    

    cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11);

    cvCanny(gray, edge, (float)edge_thresh, (float)edge_thresh*3, 5); 

    CvSeq *hand = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, hstorage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(100, 100));

    if (!hand)
    {
        printf("cvHaarDetectObjects error\n");
        system("pause");
    }

    if (hand->total <= 0)
    {
        printf("hand->total menor a cero\n");
        system("pause");
    }

    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( hand, 0 );
    cvRectangle( img,cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
        cvPoint( r->x + r->width, 
        r->y + r->height ),
        CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 
        1, 8, 0 );

    cvShowImage("camerawin",img);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is that **you people don't code safely**, forgetting to check the return of the calls every single time!

For instance, `cvHaarDetectObjects()` may not find anything. **Yes, it can detect... nothing!** When you execute your application and the camera is turned on, when there is no HAND in front of the camera it is completely understandable that `cvHaarDetectObjects()` doesn't detect anything, wouldn't you agree?

So the next call that operates on `hand` might crash or continue to return nothing, as a way to say **I FAILED**, which is what I think `cvGetSeqElem()` is doing, and then the first call that tries to dereference `r` crashes your program.

The right way to do this is:

```
CvSeq *hand = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, hstorage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(100, 100));
if (!hand)
{
  // print error, cry or exit
}

if (hand->total <= 0)
{
  // print error, cry or exit
}

CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( hand, 0 );
```

For a more complete example, check the [FaceDetection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) demo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `cvGetSeqElem()` returns NULL and you crash when you dereference `r`. The solution is to check r for being NULL before you use it (same with any other function that can fail like cvHaarDetectObjects).